# how to unlock accounts that meet certain conditions

Tags: powershell, active-directory, account, windows-server

I am trying to unlock several accounts in Active Directory through PowerShell, but I can't figure it out how to link every condition into the query

The conditions are:

-The account should be enabled

-It shouldn't be "memberof" some groups (whose I'm not able to unlock, like Administrators)

I don't have full control over accounts, I'm not able to unlock some of them, due to my privileges, so I'll be very  helpful if can you help me to know or simple discard the accounts that I'm not able to unlock

I've just tried this

```
Search-ADAccount -LockedOut | Unlock-ADAccount
```

(Very poor attempt, i know, I'm very new on this technology)

But gives me an error because of my account's privileges

[image: Error]

It says: access rights are insufficient to perform the action.
The error is the same for different CN accounts

Comment: What is your goal in doing this? Accounts are automatically unlocked after a configurable amount of time (the default is 6 minutes). See the `msDS-LockoutDuration` attribute described [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mempson/2008/07/30/fine-grain-password-policies-fgpp/) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc754461(v=ws.10))

Comment: I work in a helpdesk and for some problem migrating accounts (that's what we suppose) a lot of accounts get locked every 20 minutes aprox. Is not of our interest to solve the main problem, but I thought that if I do a script that just unlock the accounts will decrease the amount of inbound calls.

Comment: ... calls. We don't have privileges to change the policies of the lockout and the accounts are locked since 2 days ago, so maybe the  LockoutDuration is not even enabled

Comment: Since you apparently do not have permissions to unlock AD accounts, I would escalate this issue to the system administrators and let them get flooded with calls, so they either fix the problem or give you guys permission to handle AD user things like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm able to unlock some accounts, but when I run the command
> Unlock-ADAccount, I think it try to unlock accounts like
> administrator, some disabled acc, for which I don't have permission to
> modify, but if I run that command on an individual "regular" account,
> it gets unlocked

This due to the blocking of inheritance of permissions applied to domain Admins accounts & due to Security Descriptor propagator (SDPROP)....
It's not recommended, as it's a critical mechanism in my opinion, but you might :

- create a specific delegation for a group
- and append this group to the Access Control Entry (ACE) of this kind of template folder for admin permissions: 'CN=[AdminSDHolder](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22331.adminsdholder-protected-groups-and-security-descriptor-propagator.aspx),CN=System,DC=example,DC=com' (with the help of LDP.exe)

Answer (score 1):

> But gives me error**s** because of my account's privileges

That 's' in "errors" is key. If you're getting more than one error, that means that errors don't stop it from continuing on to the next account. That is, actually, how PowerShell works by default.

So what you are doing is already working the way you want it to: it is unlocking all the accounts that you have access to.

Of course, this is just a band-aid on the real problem. It won't eliminate calls for the problem accounts, and it undermines the added security you get by locking accounts in the first place.

Comment: I'm able to unlock some accounts, but when I run the command Unlock-ADAccount, I think it try to unlock accounts like administrator, some disabled acc, for which I don't have permission to modify, but if I run that command on an individual "regular" account, it gets unlocked

Comment: Right, so that's fine. It will try to unlock every locked account. If it can't unlock one, it will display an error and move on to the next one. The result is that you have unlocked every account that you can.

Comment: But after I've run the command, I check if it works running `(Search-ADAccount -LockedOut).count` and returns me the same number as before (maybe there are some others forms to check it, but this is likely my first approach to AD :/ )

Comment: Does it show you one error message (for one account), or many error messages for more than one account?

Comment: is one error message that refers to privilegegs.
I'll post it tomorrow when i'm at work